# Reveal sections as user scroll's down via navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single page with lots of sections that reveal as the user scrolls the page. Here is the fully working code.

```
/**
    * Reveal Sections as the users scrolls - Development Ongoing
    * Get the nth div of class content, where n is the contentNumber, and make it shown
    * Set intital divs to be hidden
*/

$(".reveal").addClass("noshow");
var contentNumber = 0;

function reveal() {
    var constraintNumber = contentNumber + 2;
    //IMPORTANT - DO NOT DELETE
    $(window).trigger('resize');
    //IMPORTANT - DO NOT DELETE
    for (i = contentNumber; i < constraintNumber; i++) {
        //Get the nth div of class content, where n is the contentNumber, and make it shown
        $('.reveal').eq(contentNumber).fadeIn('800');
        contentNumber ++;
    }

}
```

These sections have a style of `display:none` then when the user gets to the bottom of the window the new section appears.

The problem I have is getting my dropdown navigation to scroll down to a certain section (for example "Scroll to Section 6" even though it is hidden)

This is my scroll to code I am using:

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 17)
    }, 1000,

    function () {});
    return false;
});
```

I have this code in a FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/4Ur6R/3/

I am just looking for some help on getting the navigation to work with the reveal section. Where if you click on the navigation to scroll the sections still reveal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The navigation only seems to work when all the sections have been loaded onto the screen.

Comment: The problem is that in `reveal` you rely on the hidden `div`s' having a height of 0, and in your `click` handler you depend on their not having a height of 0. You need to use the `visibility` and `display` css properties in concert (see my answer).

Comment: I'm going to stick with the apostrophe in "`div`s'". You rely on the "quality of having", which the `div`s posses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, elements that have `display:none` don't contribute to the document height. You are using this in your `.scroll` handler, which is working great! In your `.click` handler, though, you are trying to get the `top` of an element that has no height. What you need to do is use both `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` in concert:

In your `css`,

```
.noshow {
    display:none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In your `.click` handler,

```
    // on click, add the element to the dom before calculating its height
    // it will still be visually hidden, since it has both "display:none;"
    // and "visibility:hidden"
    $(this.hash).show();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 17)
    }, 1000,

    function () {});
```

Finally, in your `reveal` function,

```
var $reveal = $('.reveal').eq(contentNumber);                       

// first change visibility to "visible", then fade it in
$('.reveal').eq(contentNumber).css("visibility", "visible").fadeIn("800");
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ur6R/22/) of my changes.